# How to invert the l-flag of grep

Tags: linux, grep

First question here, so go easy (:

I have a 385 files which are the result of simulations, named ###_result.dat.  However, some of the results resulted in errors, which I can grep for using the -l flag since these files always contain the character "=".

So getting the error-files is no problem:

```
grep -l = *_result.dat | wc -l
4
```

When I want to list the files without any errors, I thought I could just invert the grep using the v-flag:

```
grep -v -l = *_result.dat | wc -l
385
ls | wc -l
385
```

So this gives me all files, including the ones with errors.

What am I doing wrong here?

Now I know I could probably just throw out the bad ones and continue from there, but I'd like to know why this usage of grep doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `grep -L`. What you did here is find the files (`-l`) **containing lines that do not** (`-v`) match your pattern.

Comment: Never looked at it that way, but that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!